# angularjs http request to php file response back is the php file itself

Tags: php, ajax, angularjs, http

I spend some time on this error and I'm not really solving it. Everything works fine but when I get my response back, I get my php file back in plain text.

my http request:

```
.factory('getDataFactory', function ($http) {
    function myCheckList() {
        $http({
            url: 'connect.php',
            method: "GET",
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
        }).success(function (response) {
            var result = response;
            console.log(result);
        });
    }
    return myCheckList;
})
```

console log contains:

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "username");

$res = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `wereldsteden`");

$result = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {

    $result[] = $row;
}

echo json_encode($result);
?>
```

Comment: what if you add the header to your response in the php file? header("content-type:application/json");  Also I don't think you need the header on the angular side since you're not submitting any data with it

Comment: It sounds like your web server isn't set up to interpret PHP.  Are you using Apache or Nginx or something else?

Comment: I solved it already! it has to do with the netbeans connector. Instead of live conection to a port I went to my localhost. thank you for the responses

Comment: I agree with dave. Try opening `connect.php` directly in the browser